# Calculating the magnitude of a column containing vectors

Tags: r, excel, matlab, excel-formula

I have column which is used to store a physical vector quantity, say force or speed, in the following format:

```
[0 0]
[-0.011661058152260357 0.00372367132268286]
```

I wish to insert a new column which the magnitude of this vector. Calculation is simple: `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, where `x` is the first number and `y` the second.
The problem is how to read them and compute.

How can I achieved this in `Excel` or `R` or `Matlab` any way?

Comment: Are these numbers x and y of the vector, anchored at 0,0?  If so, use good old Pythagoras' theorem.  Otherwise you'll have to provide more information, like what kind of data structure you have these numbers stored in and what they represent.

Comment: @Bryan Hanson Check edit please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these numbers were stored in a data frame in `R`, then you could simply put the magnitude in a new column:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) # fake data
df$mag <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
```

which gives:

```
           x          y       mag
1 -0.1027138  0.8126019 0.8190678
2  2.4021159 -0.1336111 2.4058289
3 -1.7490194  0.8151816 1.9296605
4  0.4898490  1.2700167 1.3612106
5 -1.6132449  2.2485643 2.7674176
```

Comment: The problem is with the way x and y are stored.

Comment: There are stored in .csv file with the column mentioned containing values as [x y]. So something like a,b,c......,[x y],......g,h. Sample: 0.5,639,false,5,-1,0,0,0,[0 0]

Comment: In that case read them in with `df <- read.csv("file_name.csv", sep = " ")` if they are separated with a space.  I don't believe there is an 'on the fly' way to drop the braces.  You'd have to edit those out or re-save the data from the original source to a different format.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel:

```
=SQRT(MID(A1,2,FIND(" ",A1)-1)^2+(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND("]",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1)^2))
```